# google app script not loading JQuery Masonry from Github

Tags: jquery-plugins, github, google-apps-script, jquery-masonry, google-sites

I am trying to see if I can include JQuery plugin Masonry on a gadget on Google Sites... created from Google App script by using HtmlService to render HTML from a HTML file with:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

However... this only renderes this result:

Invalid script or HTML content: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/jquery.masonry.min.js:4+1 - 2: Unexpected token <.

I am new to Google App Scripts and testing it out. But it seems to me that it complains on an invalid token in the masonry file? Or am I interpreting this wrong? Can anybody tell me if this should be possible. I read some places it says that Google App Script is restrictive, but I do not know what to look for to see if that is the reason or not in this case.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are currently using is pointing to the GitHub information page about the file.  Changing it to the direct link to the file should solve your error:

```
https://raw.github.com/desandro/masonry/master/jquery.masonry.min.js
```

Comment: GREAT!! Thanks... The answer was so easy I feel real daft for not spotting it myself. Was there anyway I could have found this fault myself? Or did you just know out of experience? The error message did not help me... and I want to learn so that next time I know what or where to look.

Comment: @Lisa-Marie: I simply visited the page `https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/jquery.masonry.min.js` and saw that it wasn't a JavaScript file.  Right clicking the page and clicking view source confirmed the cause of the error, as I saw the HTML for the page started on line 4, which was mentioned in your error.